# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS mouse and keyboard not working on login screen

Tags: keyboard, login, 20.04, mouse

Everything goes well on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but once I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, my mouse and keyboard does not work anymore on login screen.
The fact is: they could work for a few seconds at the begining, BUT then the screen seems stucked and nothing works anymore, I could only force to restart my computer.

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I tried several things, and finally, this is what worked for me:

First, you need to enter into recovery mode:

1. Enter the grub menu by rebooting and then pressing `esc` if you boot using UEFI or `shift` if you boot using BIOS. You may have to press the key multiple times or hold the key down.
2. When you see the menu, use the arrow keys to navigate and select **`Advanced options for Ubuntu`**.
3. Select the line containing the latest version of the kernel but with **`(recovery mode)`** at the end and press `enter`.
4. After you entered recovery mode you will see the Recovery Menu. Navigate to the line containing `root` `Drop to root shell prompt`. Press `enter` and then when you see a prompt `press Enter for maintenance` press `enter` again.
5. Run the following commands:

`sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

`sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

`sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all`

6. Finally to restart run the command `sudo reboot`.

When the login page appears, your mouse and keyboard should work normally.

Note: if you get an error "Temporarily unable to fetch ....com" when running apt-get, press Ctrl+D from root prompt to go back to recovery menu and select Network in the drop down to access the internet

Comment: Thank you, this worked well for me. I was fortunate to have SSH remote access to my machine, so I simply ran the `apt` commands you shared without booting into BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, it also worked for me. But why we need this "server-xorg-input-all"? what does it do exactly? I thought it is nvidia. I uninstalled it a couple of times.

Comment: Some of us nyoobs were confused to arrive at Grub command line rather than grub menu (too many escape presses) - solution; in Grub terminal type "normal" press return, then escape - you are then back in

Comment: THANKS A LOT, it works

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04. Could someone please explain why this happened?