# Is latest upgrade (5.11.0-046-generic) causing keyboard / trackpad to stop working?

Tags: grub2, keyboard, xorg, touchpad

I have been checking out the following as my keyboard and trackpad on my macbookpro no longer work. I have followed the instructions here
[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS mouse and keyboard not working on login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259179/ubuntu-20-04-lts-mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-on-login-screen)
but I am finding if I go to grub and boot into 5.11.0-46 generic (recovery mode) I can't even select Root using the up / down keys... so as a work around I am currently running on **5.11.0-43-generic #47~20.04.2** - do I need to be in 5.11.0-46 to repair Xorg - if indeed that is the issue? apologies for numerous errors with descriptions etc; - I have experience but not expertise in Linux.

Comment: Your question is decidedly unclear. Please focus. If your latest kernel gives problems, a previous not, then stay on that previous kernel.

Comment: My apologies - my description is not correct - I will edit / update

Comment: I have found this Apparently the latest kernel does not work with some keyboards - but it does not say it affects Mac hardware; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04/1282269#1282269