# Error when starting Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, release-management

My gnome terminal won't open. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. No luck. I was able to install an Xfce terminal though. There is also a red circle with a white x on it in the lower right hand corner of my machine.

This is the error message I get:

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'Sub-process returned an error code
```

No matter whether I update, upgrade, etc. run other commands in the terminal, that doesn't seem to work. I've tried some of the other solutions for similar errors on this site and that also has not worked. I cannot use zfs snapshot because I don't have that setup for this machine either.

UPDATE: While trying to remove the PPA I ran into issues doing so, as the comments show. A comment which is now deleted, suggested looking here for answers: ["ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'" appears in various commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242009/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-appears-in-various-commands) however, while trying to implement what was shown there, it resulted in my keyboard and mouse no longer being usable once I am at the login screen. I then tried to reboot in safe mode and try repairing the machine that way with various procedures and commands (since my keyboard *was* usable there, just not at the login screen. None of the attempts to repair the system were successful.

As a last resort, I am going to create a live Ubuntu instance on a USB and see if I can do any data recovery that way, to an external drive, then reinstall the operating system.

Comment: Remove the offending PPA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Sorry for taking a bit to respond, I'm working while trying to fix this. Whenever I try to remove those PPAs, I get this error: "sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppahttp://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'"

Comment: @karel: I tried that and then ended up rebooting along the way. However, now, when I come to the login screen I am unable to use my keyboard or mouse. I am able to use the keyboard in grub and in recovery. However, even though I've tried a number of options to recover, and also tried: what is listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259179/ubuntu-20-04-lts-mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-on-login-screen. Nothing appears to be working.