# why the keyboard and mouse is not working in the login screen of ubuntu 22.04.3?

Tags: keyboard, login, mouse, screen

I tried several methods but nothing worked for me. Can anyone suggest methods for solving this?

Comment: did you see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135717/ubuntu-18-04-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-at-login-screen)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 keyboard and mouse not working at login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135717/ubuntu-18-04-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-at-login-screen)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS mouse and keyboard not working on login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259179/ubuntu-20-04-lts-mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-on-login-screen)